# Ranking results based on case insensitive matches from nested tables in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, nested-table

I am new to object relational databases and I am trying to develop a query that will return results based on the number of matches to subjects. For example, my table looks like this: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qHcW.png) My subjects type consists of two attributes (id, title). Each book can have multiple subjects and so when the user types in a string of subjects, it will return isbn, title, count(*), price ranked on the number of matches(count). I have formed the query for relational db using joins, but I am not able to reproduce it for nested tables. My relational db query is as such: `SELECT b.ISBN, b.TITLE, COUNT(*) FROM BOOKS b JOIN BOOK_SUBJECT bs ON bs.ISBN = b.ISBN WHERE bs.ID IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY b.ISBN, b.TITLE ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`.

EDIT: I am trying to search by subject title instead of id this time.

EDIT: Solution `SELECT b.ISBN, b.TITLE, count(*) FROM BOOKS2 b, table(b.subjects) d WHERE d.title like '%math%' or like '%science%' GROUP BY b.ISBN, b.TITLE ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

EDIT: How do I make it case insensitive?

Comment: Which Database you are using? If it is not Oracle then remove the Oracle tag from this question.

Comment: I have actually solved the issue already. I will edit the post with the query.

Comment: My question now is how do I make the search case insensitive? for example 'math' is same as 'Math' or 'MaTh'. I am using oracle.

Comment: changing questions makes it really hard to follow. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Now, the question title and question/answer do not match. Please edit the question title also. It will be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Please **do not edit your question to include a solution**. Instead you should post your solution as an answer. It is perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question, and even to accept it as the best solution. That's how SO works: it is a Q&A site, so threads consist of a question and one or more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment :

*My question now is how do I make the search case insensitive? for example 'math' is same as 'Math' or 'MaTh'*

You can use either `upper` or `lower` function to convert your `title` to respective form and search accordingly. Try below.

```
SELECT b.isbn, 
       b.title, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   books2 b, 
       TABLE(b.subjects) d 
WHERE  LOWER(d.title) LIKE '%math%' 
        OR LOWER(d.title) LIKE '%science%' 
GROUP  BY b.isbn, 
          b.title 
ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
```